# Getting substring of a CryptoJS's TripleDES encrypted string

Tags: javascript, php, cryptojs, tripledes

I've a legacy `php` code that encrypts with `TripleDES` method as a part of a bank flow to encrypt purchase operations. This is the code:

```
/******  3DES Function  ******/
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key){
    $l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
    return substr(openssl_encrypt($message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message)), 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"), 0, $l);
}
```

I want to reproduce the same code in `javascript` using CriptoJS's TripleDES. This is my trial so far:

```
<script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/tripledes.js></script>
<script>

    function encrypt_3DES(message, key) {
        // Parse input parameters
        message = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
        key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
        // Build an iv with zero values
        let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(64/8);
        let encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(message, key, {iv: iv});
        // Encrypt with TripleDES
        return encrypted.toString();
    }

    let message = "testMessage";
    let key = "testKey";

    let encrypted = encrypt_3DES(message, key);
    // encrypted: "HLu4p18KtFfy5VjwjFkDHA=="
    
</script>
```

Taking the example values, the result is the string `"HLu4p18KtFfy5VjwjFkDHA=="`.

The problem is that the results between `js` and `php` are slightly different, and my suspictions are pointing to the `substr` operation done on the php side, because when I'm converting the result of the `open_ssl` operation (without the substring), my javascript code is returning the same `base64` string:

```
<?php

/******  3DES Function  ******/
function encrypt_3DES($message, $key)
{
    $l = ceil(strlen($message) / 8) * 8;
    return substr(openssl_encrypt($message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message)), 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"), 0, $l);
}

$message = "testMessage";
$key = "testKey";

$res = base64_encode(encrypt_3DES($message, $key));
$res2 = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($message, 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"));

/* $res: HLu4p18KtFfTr47KvI/WEw== (My goal is to get this in javascript) */
/* $res2: HLu4p18KtFfy5VjwjFkDHA== (without the substr operation, the results match) */
?>
```

So, my question is: Is there a way to apply the same substring to the encrypted result of the javascript's CryptoJS operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code implements a custom zero padding. However, the default PKCS#7 padding is not disabled, so in addition to the explicit zero padding, a full block is unnecessarily appended by the implicit PKCS#7 padding.
This last unnecessary block is removed using `substr()`. The bottom line is that simply zero padding is used.

A more efficient PHP implementation would be to just disable the default padding with `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` instead of truncating the last block:

```php
return openssl_encrypt($message . str_repeat("\0", $l - strlen($message)), 'des-ede3-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0").
```

Anyway, in order for the C# code to return the same ciphertext as the PHP code, the padding in the C# code needs to be changed to `CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding`.

---

Note that a static IV (like the zero IV used here) is insecure, TripleDES is slow (better: AES) and zero padding is unreliable (better: PKCS#7).
Also, valid key sizes for TripleDES are [24 bytes and 16 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Keying_options).

---

**Test:**

The PHP code below:

```php
$key = '012345678901234567890123';
$message = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
print(base64_encode(encrypt_3DES($message, $key)) . PHP_EOL);
```

produces the following Base64 encoded ciphertext:

```
HNQad59lGkM83byQY2pwhluVkB7YOyIx/kGh/ibcIXQdFoiODkD1kTIIEHhqcoFm
```

The fixed JavaScript code gives the same ciphertext.

```js
function encrypt_3DES(message, key) {
    // Parse input parameters
    message = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
    key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key);
    // Build an iv with zero values
    let iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(64/8);
    let encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(message, key, {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding});
    // Encrypt with TripleDES
    return encrypted.toString();
}

let message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
let key = "012345678901234567890123";

let encrypted = encrypt_3DES(message, key);
document.getElementById("ct").innerHTML = encrypted;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="ct"></p>
```

Comment: Right on target. Using the zero padding in js side solved the issue. Thanks @Topaco